# java multithreading cpu utilization

Tags: java, multithreading, tomcat, memory-management, batch-processing

I have a application which is deployed in `tomcat 6` 
In this application I have created a `thread class` which fetches 1000 records from a table and process them and store in 4 different tables in `DataBase`.
I am running two `threads` at a time to protect the process from `deadlock`.
Is there any way to `schedule these threads` accordingly to my `cpu utilization`.
ie. If there no cpu left then new thread will not be created.

Comment: I think this question doesn't desrve a minus one. Its a good question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I correctly understood your issue, I think this case is considered in Joshua Bloch's 2nd edition of "Effective Java":

> If a server is so heavily loaded that all of its CPUs are fully
>   utilized, and more tasks arrive, more threads will be created, which
>   will only make matters worse. Therefore, in a heavily loaded
>   production server, you are much better off using
>   Executors.newFixedThreadPool, which gives you a pool with a fixed
>   number of threads, or using the ThreadPoolExecutor class directly, for
>   maximum control.

Though I haven't tried yet, using Executors seems to be a great idea.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to detect CPU utilization with pure java code. but you can call
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("top") 
then analize the inputStream result to find CPU utilization. if it is overloaded, do not start a new thread.